# Web service header

Tags: c#, web-services, service-reference

I am trying to call a web-service that has this envelope:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:kun="http://tempuri.org/AllCustomers">';
<soapenv:Header>';
 <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis- 
open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss- 
wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">';
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis- 
open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'>";
<wsse:Username>XXXXX</wsse:Username>";
<wsse:Password Type='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401- 
wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText'>PASSWORD</wsse:Password> 
</wsse:UsernameToken>";
<wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis- 
200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"></wsse:Nonce>';
<wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id=""timestamp""><wsu:Created>&Created</wsu:Created> 
</wsu:Timestamp></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>";
 <soapenv:Body>';
    <kun:AllCustomers>';
        <kun:parameters>';
            <kun:UserID >&UserID </kun:UserID >";
        </kun:parameters>';
   </kun:AllCustomers>';
</soapenv:Body>';
</soapenv:Envelope>';
```

But I keep getting an error that says:

> A 'Server' type of exception occurred during execution of
>   'AllCustomers' service.  The exception follows:
>
> com.sas.services.ServiceException: An error occurred while retrieving
>   metadata. [ com.sas.metadata.remote.MdException: The user does not
>   have permission to perform this action. [
>   com.sas.iom.SASIOMDefs.GenericError: The user does not have permission
>   to perform this action. ]  ]

This is how i make my call in:

```
using (var client = new AllCustomersPortTypeClient())
{
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "MyUserName";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "MyPassword";

    var parameter = new allCustomersParameters();
    parameter.UserID = "XXXXX";
    var request = client.allCustomers(parameter);
}
```

I think it probably has something to do with how i pass my password and username. Any suggestions?

Comment: Anyone have an idea ? would really appreciate it